# Extremal problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: you cut out white squares and put together grey squares so you get a cube without a cover/cap]

> The task is to calculate $a'$ of a square (you cut out) if the volume of a cube is maximum.

(you cut out white squares and put together grey squares so you get a cube without a cover/cap)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I try to calculate critical points I always get $0$, and there isn't even a $\max$ but a $\min$!

$V={a'}^3$
$\implies V'=3{a'}^2$

$\Rightarrow \text{critical points}: 0=3{a'}^2$ 
$\implies a'=0 (?!)$

The solution is $\dfrac{a}{6}$.

Comment: From the picture it may seem that it is a=3a' but it's not. It's just a sketch.

Comment: The flattened square is missing one side of the cube.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to. You have a square and you cut out it's borders (in shape of a square- white squares on the picture), so you get a cube without a cap/cover.

Comment: There isn't going to be any extremum if the container must be a cube(that's why you're getting $0$ as critical point since there is no variation, the solution is just a point is the solution space). A maximum will only occur if the container is a cuboid, that is, variations are allowed in the dimensions of the container.

Comment: apparently this is a task for Einstein! It's extra hard to solve it (correctly) and the one who succeedes to solve this is a genius!

Comment: You say you need to find $a$ but the solution is $\frac{a}{6}$. That doesn't even make sense. $a=\frac{a}{6}$?

Comment: The task says you need to find lenght of $a'$ and the solution is $\dfrac{a}{6}$. That's all I know + the statement $3a'=a$ which was mentioned in an answer below really confused me and can't be true. You need to find $a'$, but since we don't know the lenght of $a$ is a solution $\dfrac{a}{6}$. I'm still trying to solve this task and if I succeed I'll post an aswer to this question. But thank you for asking and noticing!

Comment: Anja97 $\;a = 3a'$ is evident from the first image: to make an open-topped cube, we need a (left) side of length $a'$, the bottom of length $a'$, and the (right) side of length $a'$ to make a open-topped cube. That means the square of length $a$ needs to be $3a'$ wide (and $3a'$ high, since it's a square.) Can you see that $a\times a = 3a' \times 3a' \implies a = 3a'?$ Each side of the $a\times a$ square is divided into equal thirds of length $a'$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$3a' = a\implies a' = \frac 13 a$$

$$V = a'^3\implies V = \left(\frac 13 a\right)^3 = \frac 1{27} a^3$$

$$V' = \frac 19a^2$$

Comment: isn't over here a solution a^2/6 and not a/6?

Comment: @MasterOfBinary You're right the solution over here is a^2/9 and it's supposed to be a/6.

Comment: No, Anja97: $V'(a) = \frac 19a^2$ Be clear about what you need to find. You say you need to find $a$: that's impossible. We can find the derivative of $V'$ in terms of $a$, but it's not $a/6$.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, but this can't be the answer to this task, because you're supposed to write how much  the lenght of (side) a is.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to determine the maximum volume in terms of $a$, there is no maximum to volume, as posted. As $a$ increases without bound, so does $V$. Did you, perhaps, leave out information about any constraints on $a$? For example, constraints on surface area?

Comment: No, that's all information the task is providing (unfortunatelly). It only says that a is a side of a square and that you get a cube without a cover.